# How do you test that a function fired from a VUE 3 watch in vittest?

Tags: vuejs3, vitest

In my VUE 3 component I have some code like this:

```
const page = ref(1)
const size = ref(25)
const sort = ref(new Array<Order>()>

watch([page, size, sort], () => doCaseSearch(searchProps.value)
```

The code works but now I want to write a vitest to verify that the watch fires when the page changes value.  I've tried several approaches such as this one with no success:

```
it('should call doCaseSearch when page changes', async () => {
     const doCaseSearchSpy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'doCaseSearch')
     wrapper.vm.page = 7
     await flushPromises()
     expect(doCaseSearchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

Any suggestions on how to correctly do this?  Thanks.